# Multidimensional vector solution using c++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

I Would like to try the below mentioned implementation using C++ STL.
My requirement is to create a Matrix mentioned below.
The string of vectors are :

[image]

Basically i would want to update the matrix counting the no of Man/woman/kids.
For eg Based on the Sample Input mentioned below ,expected output is: 
For Tokyo => Man=1, Woman=1, Kid=0 .

The approach I think is to first sort the Cities and get the unique values.
and then similarly do it for Man, Woman & Kids. Then count the no of Man/Woman/kids for that city. To do this which kind of container would be ideal, ordered map ? How should i handle such multidimensional array problems.
What would be the most efficient way to handle this kind of situation.Any other solution would be highly appreciated.

### Sample Input

[image]

### Expected Output [ will be filled accordingly, please ignore empty fields]

[image]

Comment: What about `std::map<City, std::map<Category, int> > data;`? Then just read `city` and `category` from the file and do `++data[city][category]`.

Comment: While for short keys, `std::vector` and a sequential search is likely faster, if performance is not paramount, I prefer the `std::map` syntax. Of course, you could try with `std::unordered_map` and get (part of) the best of both options.

Comment: Are the cities and the categories just those one you wrote? If so, the most efficient way is just a fixed sized C array or a std::array

Comment: Please do not abuse of images! A good SO question should be understandable even if the images are blocked. And here *ascii art* in code formatted paragraphs would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether the possible values of any dimensions are know a priori or not. If they are, a simple array will be the best container, else you should use a map. If order does not matter, use an `unordered_map`, if you can sort it, use an ordered `map`, and if you want to keep input order, use a `list` where the indexes are stored in a map.

If the categories are known to get only 3 possible values (Man, Woman, Kid) and the cities are not known a priori, I would use:

```
std::map<std::string, std::array<int, 3> > resul;

std::string town, cat;
for(;;) {
    std::cin >> town >> cat;
    if (! std::cin) break;
    if (resul.find(town) == resul.end()) {
        resul[town].fill(0);
    }
    std::array<int, 3>& curtown = resul[town];
    if (cat == "Man") curtown[MAN] += 1;
    else if (cat == "Woman") curtown[WOMAN] += 1;
    else curtown[KID] += 1;
}
```

Comment: The dimensions of city is unknown but the category can be fixed to 3